# Indirect questions with passive voice: "Could you tell me what time..."

Tags: modal-verbs, questions

There is the questions

> What time is breakfast served?

how should I create an indirect question?

> Could you tell me what time breakfast served?

or probably

> Could you tell me what time breakfast is served?

So I should omit verb to be, right?

Answer (score 1):

Your second example is a correct indirect question: "Could you tell me what time breakfast **is** served?"

When making an indirect question, the verb from the original question is still important. Consider the difference between:

> Could you tell me what time breakfast is served?
>
> Could you tell me what time breakfast was served?
>
> Could you tell me what time breakfast would be served?

It would be the same with other ways to ask an indirect question about this:

> Could I ask what time breakfast is served?
>
> It would be great to know what time breakfast is served.
>
> Is there any chance you could check what time breakfast is served?

The word order from the original question, "What time *is* breakfast served?", changes to the word order of a statement, "What time breakfast *is* served", which is used in any indirect question you might ask just as if it were a noun phrase.

Comment: Actually, it's not a noun phrase but an interrogative clause (embedded question) serving as complement of the relevant verb.

Comment: @BillJ, good note, thank you, and granted. I don't want to get too technical in my answer, so I've clarified my wording to say "just as if it were a noun phrase", is that accurate enough?